# What three files are always opened by a process?

Tags: files, process, standard

Someone mentioned that there are three different files that a process always opens. What does this mean? What files are they?

Answer (score 11):

The files that are opened are not files on disk. They are the streams (pseudo files), stdin (0), stdout (1), and stderr (2). Here is the relevant excerpt from the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stdin.html):

> A file with associated buffering is called a stream and is declared to
>   be a pointer to a defined type FILE. The fopen() function shall create
>   certain descriptive data for a stream and return a pointer to
>   designate the stream in all further transactions. Normally, there are
>   three open streams with constant pointers declared in the 
>   header and associated with the standard open files.
>
> At program start-up, three streams shall be predefined and need not be
>   opened explicitly: standard input (for reading conventional input),
>   standard output (for writing conventional output), and standard error
>   (for writing diagnostic output). When opened, the standard error
>   stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output
>   streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined
>   not to refer to an interactive device.