# Which processes have standard file descriptors?

Tags: terminal, process, stdout, stdin, stderr

Which is the correct statement?

> Every Unix process has the standard file descriptors open: standard input, standard output and standard error.

or

> Every Unix process attached to a terminal has the standard file descriptors open: standard input, standard output and standard error.

Comment: The latter statement follows from the first statement. They do not contradict each other.

Comment: Which is the precise statement, then?

Comment: It would be wrong for me to do your home work for you, but I will help. Read https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKzonnwoR2I and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)

Comment: By convention, every process has the three descriptors open. On the other hand, they can be closed.

Comment: @JohanMyréen thanks. So the process creating system calls create all processes with the three standard file descriptors, but some dissociate from their terminal, as I see now.

Answer (score 2):

They're both wrong.

```
sleep 999 <&- >&- 2>&-
^C
```

The `sleep 999` Unix process has no standard file descriptors open, but it's still attached to the terminal since I'm able to kill it with Control-C.

Comment: I guess this comes down to how you interpret "attached to the terminal".

Comment: Attached to a terminal means having it as its [controlling terminal](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Controlling-Terminal.html). I haven't invented the phrase (example: [reptyr](https://blog.nelhage.com/2011/01/reptyr-attach-a-running-process-to-a-new-terminal/) "attaches a running process to a new terminal") and I don't know any other way in which it could be interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a multiple choice exam question then tick the first.  The teacher wants you to understand these standard file descriptors are **usually** open for any process, not just those attached to the terminal.

However no process is absolutely guaranteed to be started with these, except the very first process at startup.  You can argue that the second statement is more true because without these open it's no longer really attached to the terminal any more (debatable).

---

What is true?

Every process is allowed to [close()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/close.html) or replace any of its file descriptors, including STDIN STDOUT STDERR.  Once closed they are *gone* and no longer exist as an FD at all.  All file descriptors held by a child process are inherited from the parent.  So if one process closes these three standard file descriptors and then creates a child, the child will not have them either.

To be clear this is incorrect:

> So the process creating system calls create all processes with the three standard file descriptors, but some dissociate from their terminal

If the parent process dissociate from the terminal by closing it's descriptors and not replacing them with [dup2()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html), the child will not have them.  If that child creates its own child then the "grandchild" will not have them either...

---

For a posix reference on this you need to understand that executing a program is usually done with a combination of:

- `fork()` to start a child process
- `execve()` in the child process to run a different program

[According to posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) fork() inherits all file descriptors:

> The child process shall have its own copy of the parent's file descriptors. Each of the child's file descriptors shall refer to the same open file description with the corresponding file descriptor of the parent.

There's one further trip hazard.  Some file descriptors can be set to automatically close when calling [execve()](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execve.html):

> File descriptors open in the calling process image shall remain open in the new process image, except for those whose close-on- exec flag FD_CLOEXEC is set.

So even if the parent has not explicitly closed a file descriptor it may not exist for the child program.

Answer (score -2):

With all the hostile comments, I suggest the following answer:

[What three files are always opened by a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198515/what-three-files-are-always-opened-by-a-process)

this contains a link to the POSIX standard:

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/stdin.html

> At program start-up, three streams shall be predefined and need not be opened explicitly: standard input (for reading conventional input), standard output (for writing conventional output), and standard error (for writing diagnostic output). When opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.